# What exactly connects the two phrases in encyclopedic sentences like these?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

This particular phrasing seems common on for instance Wikipedia articles:

> Considered one of the most influential figures in the history of the motion picture, he pioneered many aspects of film editing and expanded the art of the narrative film.

[D. W. Griffith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D._W._Griffith)

> A member of the Democratic Party, he was the first African-American president.

[Barack Obama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama)

> A member of the Nerva-Antonine dynasty and one of the so-called "Five Good Emperors", he is renowned for his travels throughout the empire and the civil and military constructions of his reign.

[Hadrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian)

What is the logic behind combining a phrasal description of a person with what's essentially a new complete sentence about them, with a comma? Is it typical encyclopedia language, the way newspaper headlines have their own grammar rules, or is this a specific instance of a more versatile form?

Comment: I would rewrite the first and break up the others.  The form connotes hasty journalism, where the writer has a list of ‘human interest’ details (“mother of two”, “avid golfer”) that have to be stuck in somewhere, and tacks them onto arbitrary sentences in this way.

Comment: @AntonSherwood it doesn't save much space. Each of them can be made more conventional in structure by writing first the second phrase, then "and is" or "and was", and then the first phrase. "He was the first African-American president and is a member of the Democratic Party". So my impression is that it is deliberate.

Comment: It's perfectly natural in such contexts as encyclopaedias and biographies. In conversation, it would sound absurdly stilted.

Comment: "A member of the Democratic Party" -  **A noun phrase describing a person's political affiliation. In this context,it implies the person being referred to is associated with the Democratic Party.**

Comment: @Sam I know what those sentences mean. I'm falling over the form "noun phrase, comma, sentence". Is that journalistic, encyclopedic, archaic, clumsy? I want to understand how and in what contexts I should be using that, if ever.

Comment: The style of the 2 last sentences would be lighter if the initial article "A" is removed.

Comment: The grammatical term for this is construction is  [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition). On grammarist : [Appositive Phrases and How to Use Them in a Sentence](https://grammarist.com/grammar/appositives/), on [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/appositive/), etc.

Comment: Can you not see a connection between (1) being an influential figure in film and (2) pioneering many techniques used in film? You seem to suggest these facts are unconnected, but the sentence indicates a connection.

Comment: Compare "Made from a single piece of wood, the beam is very strong."

Comment: @StuartF I understand that the facts are related, the question isn't about that. It's about the grammatical construction. None clarified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure is called **[apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition#Examples)**:

> **Apposition** is a grammatical construction in which two elements, normally noun phrases, are placed side by side so one element identifies the other in a different way.

This structure is often used to present two pieces of information about the same thing at once, or to restrict the meaning of a phrase. These functions are very similar to *non-defining* and *defining relative clauses*.

The main phrase is called the *phrase in apposition<sup>P</sup>*, while the secondary phrase that describes the same thing is called the *appositive phrase<sup>A</sup>*, or more commonly, just the *appositive*.

Here are some simple examples:

> My niece<sup>P</sup>, a horse lover<sup>A</sup>, runs a children's summer camp.
> My nephew<sup>P</sup> the electrician<sup>A</sup> plays a lot of hockey.
> A marvel of engineering<sup>A</sup>, the Hagia Sophia<sup>P</sup> was the largest church in the world for nearly 1,000 years.

In your sentence about Obama, the bit before the comma is the *appositive phrase*, and "he" is the *phrase in apposition*.

It's often used in writing having a series of simple sentences is bad style, and comes off as childish writing. *Apposition* is a clear way to incorporate more meaning into fewer words.

The reason this structure appears so often in Wikipedia articles in particular, is because on that platform, someone writes a simple sentence, then someone else wants to add more information about the subject of that sentence, but doesn't want to leave a childish series of simple sentences, to they add their information as an *appositive phrase* before the subject in some random sentence. This practice often results in sloppy writing on Wikipedia.

In that Obama article, somebody probably wrote the simple sentence, "He was the first African-American president", and then later, someone added the fact he was a member of the Democratic Party, and chose to attach it to that sentence, rather than create a new one. This ends up sloppy because his party affiliation should not be in the same sentence as his being the first African-American president.

Answer (score 1):

In these sentences, the first part gives us quick facts about the person. It's like a short introduction. Then, a comma separates this introduction from more details that follow. This way, you get to know something important about the person right away, and then you learn more. Of course, it's connected in terms of content. But there is also a more advanced connection technique that sounds counterintuitive.

When you're writing, sometimes using connecting words like "and," "because," or "however" helps to guide the reader from one idea to the next. One can often skip these connecting words, and the sentences still make sense. This can actually make the writing flow better, for various reasons, *especially* if the connecting words do not add detail, which is commonly the case for "and" or "specifically."

Answer (score 1):

*Edited content upon request.*

From the comments:

> I'm falling over the form "noun phrase, comma, sentence". Is that journalistic, encyclopedic, archaic, clumsy? I want to understand how
> and in what contexts I should be using that, if ever.
> – KeizerHarm (OP)

Not limited to this particular sentence structure, these are examples of [appositives](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/appositive_apposition.htm). These noun phrases are convenient because, generally, they allow a writer to manipulate their placement adjacent to any related noun in the sentence without a drastic impact on the original meaning.

The noun phrases in question are essential to the meaning of the noun they modify. As such, they are expressed with the structure that is being asked about (*noun phrase-comma-sentence*) where a second comma does not offset the subject of the *sentence*.

Using a variety of sentence structures can help to keep one's writing from reading monotonous or uninteresting. This structure is especially useful if you start a piece using an outline in which you have bullet points listing a number of related facts that you want to link together.

The example for Hadrian is just a bit awkward in that the progression does not feel natural to me. In outline form it might look something like this:

Hadrian

- a member of the Nerva-Antonine dynasty
- one of the so-called "Five Good Emperors"
- renowned for his travels throughout the empire
- renowned for the civil and military constructions of his reign

Each of these bullet points could be turned into a complete sentence on its own and presented separately, but that could wear on a reader. Combining them as in the example doesn't break the rules for using appositives, but their arrangement calls attention to itself. As the writer, it comes down what you consider awkward. A sentence written by me, using the bullet points above and the structure in question, would look like this:

**Hadrian**
*One of the so-called “Five Good Emperors” and a member of the Nerva-Antoine dynasty,  he is renowned for his travels throughout the empire and remembered for the civil and military constructions of his reign.*

This particular structure helps a writer to maintain a relationship among the bullet points of information by tying at least one phrase to the subject of the sentence. As such, the writer can guide the reader subtly by listing the data points with consideration to an order of importance in how they relate to the subject.

*Five Good Emperors* grabs a reader's attention and holds it through the information about the dynasty. Next, *is renowned* and *(is) remembered* subtly add a sense of time to the progression by establishing a relative separation between the last two data points, one of which has an internal compound. This helps the sentence to flow more smoothly.

[Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/appositive_apposition.htm) and [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/appositive/) offer good explanations of some of the intricacies about using punctuation for restrictive and non-restrictive appositives.

Re: *Is that* (the style) *journalistic, encyclopedic, archaic, clumsy?* - from OP's question in the comments.

This syntactical structure is one I recognize from political ads, such as: *A family man, Joe Senator promises to be tough on crime.*

*Family* and *tough on crime* become soundbites that may connote *stability* and *protection*. In a few seconds, Joe Senator has linked himself to these two desirable concepts for a politician. When received aurally, the noun phrases lose some of their disparity by virtue of their link to the subject. As such, it can be useful for persuasive speech.

Regarding the original question beginning: *What is the logic behind combining a phrasal description of a person with what's essentially a new complete sentence about them, with a comma?* This entry for [False Titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title#) on Wiki seems relevant:

> A false, coined, fake, bogus or pseudo-title, also called a Time-style
> adjective and an anarthrous nominal premodifier, is a kind of
> appositive phrase before a noun predominantly found in journalistic
> writing.

Among those [Opposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title#Opposed_to_false_titles) to False Titles:
*The Columbia Guide to Standard American English (1993) classifies these constructions as "[journalese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journalese)".*

This may be why the example sentences in the original question convey a journalistic quality. It is not an exact match, however, because there is this distinction (from the same [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_title#Opposed_to_false_titles) above):

> An example is the phrase *convicted bomber* in "convicted bomber Timothy
> McVeigh", rather than "the convicted bomber Timothy McVeigh".

Comment: It's great that you've corrected your answer, but please remove everything that's chatter, rather than part of a direct answer to the question. For instance, why you made a mistake doesn't answer the question, nor your experience while writing the Hadrian sentence, nor what intrigues you about the question. Also, if a source is incorrect, like "*Appositive noun phrases are nonrestrictive*", it's better not to include it.

Answer (score 0):

This construction is popular in journalistic style. I would say it belongs to formal (or semi-formal) written genres; it would be unusual in conversation.